# Dynamically positioning drawing outside of screen in expression blend

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, expression-blend

So, I am using expression blend to make an animation, and I would like to animate something coming from off screen to the center of the screen. Simple example in these pictures:

[image: Start off screen]

[image: Go to center screen]

Please forgive me as I am pretty new to using Blend. So my problem is that I want this to work on any size monitor and any resolution. This is why I simply can't just hard code a number for its translation. If I wanted something to come in from the right side of the screen, I could just use the System Resource for maximized screen size, and that would work on all monitors. Since XAML doesnt support arithmetic operations, I can't simply use the negative size of the maximized screen size. I was thinking there could be a way of making my own resource, but I don't know how I would get the screen size for something like that. Any ideas on how to move my object off screen based on the screen size?

Comment: Without just hard coding a value that will accomodate all screen sizes on a TranslateTranform (which is what I do since it's easy and users will never tell the difference) I'd think you'd have to throw a converter on it to grab the current ActualWidth and pad on an extra allotment for the size of whatever you're bringing in. Otherwise could just start it from the left with a Zero width, then animate the full width and slide it in and try to fake it.

Comment: I had read somewhere it is bad practice to use values that are way out of the screen boundaries. Have you heard this? Any reason for it? Do you see any problems with hard coding such a large value?